# Newly upgraded Ubuntu 11.04 VM not booting

Tags: linux, virtualbox, grub, ubuntu-11.04

I have just upgraded to 11.04 on my VirtualBox VM, and after I start it, it begins to load, but it stops at the line `* Checking battery state... [ OK ]`

I have tried the recovery mode, but to no avail. I can access the boot commands and the command line, but I have no idea what to do from either.

Before the above line, there is a highlighted line
`* PulseAudio configured for per-user sessions

saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned`

Comment: Fire up a liveCD in VirtualBox. Mount the "/" partition of your guest and check "/var/log" for messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was having the same problem, and I found a solution here in [hnyman's post](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=40893#p185230):

> I solved the problem by getting into
>   the console mode (Ctrl-Alt-F1) and
>   logging into Ubuntu from that console,
>   then I manually created a mount point
>   for the cdrom and mounted the Guest
>   Additions cdrom, and finally did run
>   the Guest additions script. That
>   solved the problem.
>
> ```
> sudo mkdir /media/cdrom
> sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom/
> sudo /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
> ```
>
> So, it might be advisable to uninstall
>   Guest Additions before the upgrade
>   from 10.10 to 11.04, as the old
>   version might prevent the upgraded
>   system to boot properly into desktop.
>
> Ps. After enabling the 3D accleration
>   in VirtualBox guest system settings,
>   the Unity booted ok, but I decided to
>   stay with the old classic desktop for
>   the time being.